# How to set TTL on ServiceBus ManagementClient CreateSubscriptionAsync

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, ttl, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

When I create a subscription as follows the TTL is defaulted to 10675199 days

```
var client = new ManagementClient(connStr);

if (!await client.SubscriptionExistsAsync(topicName, subscriptionName))
{
    // TODO: this has an unlimited TTL, which needs to be reduced to 1 day.
    client.CreateSubscriptionAsync(topicName, subscriptionName); 
}
```

How can this be set from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the overloading method of `CreateSubscriptionAsync` which takes `SubscriptionDescription` as parameter.

Like below:

```
var sd = new SubscriptionDescription(topicName, subscriptionName)
{
    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)

};

if (!await client.SubscriptionExistsAsync(topicName, subscriptionName))
{
    client.CreateSubscriptionAsync(sd);
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/56b647aeaf0ed5a58e5b8030aca055548bbabce4/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/tests/Management/ManagementClientTests.cs#L174) for more details.